# Adding a New one-to-one Parent-Child Record Saying Model Is Not Valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this model:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Name is Required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SkillSet SkillSet { get; set; }
}

public class SkillSet {
    public int SkillSetId { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Using this Partial View Rendered in a Form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EmployeeId)
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="span2">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "" })</div>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SkillSet.SkillSetId)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SkillSet.EmployeeId)
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"><strong>Programming Skills</strong></div>
    <div class="span2">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SkillSet.Programming, new { @class = "" })</div>
</div>
```

I populate the form from get by returning a new instance of the Employee for posting, but when I try to save the new record there is an error in ModelState regarding the `SkillSet.SkillSetId` being empty for the new record.

What am I missing here to add the new parent-child record to my db?

EDIT:
I've got it to work now. My problem was just the rendering of the Hidden Fields for my form. I had to put the hidden fields in a div and they rendered fine and I was able to handle the data from post back.

Comment: Can you post your controller action where you try to save your model?

Comment: Can't suggest you anything until you post your Controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You posted not enough code to draw some conclusion, but I can tell you this: it doesn't seem like a problem between controller/view and model, it seems to be a problem in the database.

*In your skillset table (whatever you call it) the ID, which appears to be `SkillSetId` should be defined as key and identifier*.

Another thing I noticed and don't like in your model is that you have a circular referencing (Employee points to SkillSet, SkillSet points to Employee). Entity Framework doesn't like it and may cause you problems you don't anticipate. Since its a view model its OK, but if your database defined the same way - consider redefining it.

Hope this helps you in your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I'll be checking on my database and update my model. I'll let you know what I find.

Thank you very much!